# Build exception with cordova-plugin-smooch

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, smooch

I'm trying to integrate smooch into my Cordova app with the [official plugin](https://github.com/smooch/smooch-cordova) but when I go to build my application it throws a main thread exception back at me. Here's (what I think are the relevant parts of) my build output, if you need any more just comment and I'll put it up.

```
:app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebugException in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:108)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer$DefaultMethodFinder.visit(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:471)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.defaultMethodsDefined(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:319)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.visitEnd(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:88)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.InterfaceDesugaring.visitEnd(InterfaceDesugaring.java:85)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring.visitEnd(LambdaDesugaring.java:150)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:401)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:326)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:280)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:584)
```

The rest is at: https://pastebin.com/9j0ZW7rJ

I've followed the Android installation instructions, changed my app-id and all of that guff... I'm not sure but I have a hunch it might be conflicting with https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase since they both handle fcm messages and I've had problems like that before.

Here are the other plugins in my app:

```
cordova-plugin-firebase 0.1.25 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-headercolor 1.0 "HeaderColor"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.1 "StatusBar"
```

If anyone has any ideas for what to try, has had this problem before and knows what's going on, I'd love your help! There's an [issue over on github](https://github.com/smooch/smooch-cordova/issues/40) but not sure if smooch is maintaining the plugin anymore.

Comment: It may be related to conflicting firebase versions. You can verify this by running the `dependencies` task on your Android app. Ex: `./gradlew myapp:dependencies`. Smooch uses firebase-core, firebase-messaging, and play-services-location. It seems like the cordova plugin uses firebase-crash and firebase-auth. All of them should run with the same version

Comment: Hey, @wmora thanks for replying :) I ran `gradlew app:dependencies --configuration compile` and got this: https://pastebin.com/hG4h36JP it looks like the firebase-core dependencies are shared but are actually playing nice with each other. See anything I didn't spot?

Comment: Got it, it was a dependency issue, it looks like `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location` is called at version 11.0.4 while everything else is at 11.8.0. Adding the dependencies to build.gradle manually fixed this (for good measure I also explicitly set the firebase version) thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a Cordova specific issue at all, thanks to wmora for pointing me towards dependencies.

First, run `gradlew myapp:dependencies` inside your app (for cordova projects, this is /platforms/android) and make sure that all of your dependencies match up correctly.

If not, head over to /platforms/android/app/build.gradle and down to dependencies and add the dependency along with an explicit version number.

(This is what I needed, might not work for you)

```
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0"
```

(for cordova projects, outside it after the last quote inside your dependency brackets to make sure cordova doesn't overwrite it)

Clean, build and hopefully you should be good to go!

Comment: I solved the problem by using the SAME version number for firebase and play-services in /platforms/android/app/build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

```
cordova clean
```

that line help me. if still have problem, try

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release
```